# Are magnetic poles arbitrary?

Tags: electromagnetism

Is there any physical difference between north and south poles of a magnet?
I was thinking about the Earth swapping poles then went on this mental tangent. Can an definitive observation be made without referencing the Earth's magnetic field? I was looking online and it's like hunting for a needle in a haystack, but it also makes a point that the poles are usually determined by the flow of the electricity that created them in the magnetizer or by referencing another magnetic field. But all magnets got their 'north' assigned way back when man first discovered the alignment to Earth's. And Electricity was understood long after magnets, so they too have the polarity assigned, by way of magnets, from the Earth's magnetic pole, even at the atomic level. I understand the right hand rule and all that, but what I am curious about is if there is any any physical difference?

I think the answer might be that it's just an axiom of nature. Poles just are. And that all of our notion of which is "positive", and why maps have north at the top, was becasue the floated lodestone pointed to the star, aptly named Polaris, that didn't appear to move. And that if the Earth's field was swapped, all references in physics now would be reversed. But my knowledge of physics is very limited so maybe there's more too it.

Comment: In electrodynamics, this stuff is all a matter of convention. There's a physical difference in the case of the weak interaction but that was one of the big surprises of the 20th century.